# Undefined symbol errors when building XCode project from Unity (Firebase)

Tags: xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

I have just finished creating a game in Unity and a built to Xcode. Once built, I opened a terminal and ran pod install to install firebase packages which generated a workspace file. I then opened the workspace file to try build the project and during the build it resulted in a fail with the following errors:

```
Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_Variant_FromDouble

Undefined symbol: _SWIGRegisterExceptionArgumentCallbacks_StorageInternal

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_Variant_FromInt64

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_Storage_CSharp_MonitorControllerInternal_BytesTransferred_get

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_FirebaseUser_UpdateUserProfile

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_Variant_double_value

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_Variant_int64_value

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_Variant_is_fundamental_type

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_VariantVariantMap_setitem

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_Variant_map__SWIG_0

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_Variant_vector__SWIG_0

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_Variant_blob_size

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_Variant_untyped_mutable_blob_data

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_Variant_EmptyMutableBlob

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_Future_User_GetResult

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_CreateIdTokenListener

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_delete_UserProfile

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_Variant_EmptyMap

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_Variant_EmptyVector

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_Storage_CSharp_StorageReferenceInternal_IsValid_get

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_new_UserProfile

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_DestroyIdTokenListener

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_Storage_CSharp_FirebaseStorageInternal_GetReferenceFromUrl__SWIG_0

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FixAndroidDependencies

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_Variant_Null

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_VariantVariantMap_Add

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_delete_VariantList

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_VariantList_getitem

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_Database_CSharp_InternalDatabaseReference_url
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Check for Firebase plugin, it should be present in your project - earlier it was not there for me.

Unity project should look like this. [image: See the Window pane, if Firebase documentation is visible then only Project is reading Google service files] and this will resolve the issue

Add files under this path "./Assets/Firebase/Editor",follow this link https://github.com/techyworm10/firebase-unity-sdk-editor-python-fix

Comment: Were you using the .xcworkspace file to launch your project in XCode from the podfile or just the standard .xcodeproj file. Thank you for your help!

Comment: With Podfile, always use workspace not standard project file.

Comment: They are not in my plugins folder they are in a folder. Is there a way I can download these files? Is my unity set up incorrectly when migrating from XCode to Unity

Comment: So I did a workaround, seems like you have system with OS version Monterey 12.3.1 - with this we need to add Files under "./Assets/Firebase/Editor" this path. Follow the link I am adding in the answer and see if you get results

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. One final question where exactly is ./firebase-unity-sdk/editor/app/src/PythonExecutor.cs. I am working from my windows PC then building zipping and sending the folder to my macbook for it to be unzipped and ran. Where is that folder located so I can rename it from python to python3. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of this folder, just try adding Firebase.Editor files under "./Assets/Firebase/Editor". Only doing this solved my issue